# C# linq order by depending on Language

Tags: c#, linq

```
String[] a = new String[] { "NIKE", "한글","adidas","한글Korean" };
```

I like to order the array,  the `한글` is first

if I just order without options.   the English String is always on top.

how can I do this?

Comment: Your English was fine until 'horrible' :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An overload of `OrderBy` takes an `IComparer<string>` and you can get one of these for a specific culture using the static `Create` method on `StringComparer`. Something like this should work:

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ko-KR"); 
bool ignoreCase = true; //whether comparison should be case-sensitive
StringComparer comp = StringComparer.Create(ci, ignoreCase);

string[] unordered = //whatever
var ordered = unordered.OrderBy(s => s, comp);
```